# How to get the maxBound of a type that has a Bounded instance

Tags: haskell, bounded-types

The following Haskell code does not compile:

```
getMaxBound :: (Bounded a) => a -> a
getMaxBound _ = maxBound :: a
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Could not deduce (Bounded a1) arising from a use of ‘maxBound’
  from the context: Bounded a
    bound by the type signature for:
               getMaxBound :: Bounded a => a -> a
    at rot13.hs:3:1-36
```

Why can't I get the maxBound of a bounded type in Haskell?

Ideally, I would use this function like this:

```
getMaxBound 3
> 9223372036854775807

getMaxBound 'c'
> '\1114111'
```

I feel like every time I have any type `a` which has a Bounded instance, I should be able to get the maxBound of that type.

What am I missing?

Comment: The `a` in the body is another `a` as the one in the signature.

Comment: How to point `maxBound` to the `a` in the signature?

Comment: you already did in the `a -> a` signature.

Comment: all you need as ``maxBound `asTypeOf` (undefined::Int)``. no need to define your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Type signature is sufficient

Since the signature already restricts the type, you can drop the `:: a` part in the function body:

```
getMaxBound :: Bounded a => a -> a
getMaxBound _ = maxBound
```

The type signature specifies that type of the input of the function is the same as the type of the output of the function.

For example:

```
Prelude> getMaxBound (3 :: Int)
9223372036854775807
Prelude> getMaxBound 'c'
'\1114111'
Prelude> getMaxBound True
True
Prelude> getMaxBound LT
GT
```

## Using the [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XScopedTypeVariables) extension

We can also use the [**`ScopedTypeVariables`** extension [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables), and then implement it with a reference to the `a` type variable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

getMaxBound :: forall a . Bounded a => a -> a
getMaxBound _ = maxBound :: a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interesting! If I had a more complex functions that returned different type, let's say type `b`, would it still be possible in Haskell to mean the `maxBound` of `a` ?

Comment: @MMacphail: if you define it as `a -> b`, then this would not work, since then you basically say "the return value is a free choice" whereas the function body suggests it is not.

Comment: And what of functions where the context is important ? 

    rotN :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => a -> a
    rotN c = toEnum rotation
      where alphabetSize = fromEnum (maxBound) + 1
            halfAlphabet = alphabetSize `div` 2
            offset = fromEnum c + halfAlphabet
            rotation = offset `mod` alphabetSize

In this example, if I don't specify the type of maxBound, the compiler can't decide, but if I specify `a` the compiler tells me type `a1` is unknown... When I really want the `a` in signature.

Answer (score 5):

Willem's answer should work just fine in this case, but an alternative that might also be useful in more complicated cases is to use `-XScopedTypeVariables`

if you add the line `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to the top of the file, your code should compile.

what the extension does is to allow you to reference the type variables from an outer scope in an inner scope. in your code, `a` gets shadowed in the function body, and there is no connection between it and the outer `a`, causing you to lose the `Bounded a` context!

Comment: Lol, we updated at (almost) exactly the same time :)

Comment: Thanks, both of your answers were great :) I didn't know about the shadowing.